# What is the use of curly braces { } in R, and in this code snippet?

Tags: r

Here, `deck` contains all 52 cards in the deck. `aces` contains the 4 ace cards. `facecard` contains the 10, J, Q, K of all suits.

```
results <- replicate(B, {
   hand <- sample(deck, 2)
   (hand[1] %in% aces & hand[2] %in% facecard)
})
```

Q1. What is the use of the { } brace here?
Q2. When we assign 2 vectors to `hand`, we then pass a logical statement in the same line. How is that allowed?

I have tried searching for the use of the curly braces in R but to no avail, and I can't for the life of me understand the use of the logical statement outside the `sample()` function and on the same line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The braces indicate that the whole expression inside them is a single argument passed to the `replicate` function. The code means "replicate the result of this whole expression `B` times". Without the braces, the line break after `sample(deck, 2)` would cause a parser error. Line breaks are syntactically important in R, so the line `(hand[1] %in% aces & hand[2] %in% facecard)` is a different line of code and is evaluated after `hand <- sample(deck, 2)`. It is the output of this line that is returned `B` times from the `replicate` function.

The line `hand <- sample(deck, 2)` means generate a length-2 vector whose elements are drawn at random from the vector `deck`, *not* draw 2 vectors.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for the first paragraph and second paragraph. Fully understood it. If I might make an addition to your answer: 'When multiple statements are included in a { } expression, the last line in the { } expression is output". Is this correct in saying?

Comment: @SuperAwesomeCaptainMcFluffyPa it just means `deck` is a vector of all the cards in a deck, and `sample(deck, 2)` just means "choose 2 cards at random"